# Linux find and delete files but redirect file names to be deleted

Tags: linux, find, command, delete-file

Is there a way to **write the file names to a file** before they are deleted for reference later to check what has been deleted.

```
find <PATH> -type f -name "<filePattern>" -mtime +1 -delete
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just add a `-print` expression to the invocation of `find`:

```
find <PATH> -type f -name "<filePattern>" -mtime +1 -delete -print > log
```

I'm not sure if this prints the name before or after the file is unlinked, but it should not matter.  I suspect `-delete -print` unlinks before it prints, while `-print -delete` will print before it unlinks.

Answer (score 8):

Like William said, you can use `-print`. However, instead of `-print > log`, you can also use the `-fprint` flag.

You'd want something like:

```
find <PATH> -type f -name "<filePattern>" -mtime +1 -fprint "<pathToLog>" -delete
```

For instance, I use this in a script:

```
find . -type d -name .~tmp~ -fprint /var/log/rsync-index-removal.log -delete
```

Comment: fprint overwites the file;
Wouldn't it be better to append to file???
I have looked at the manual but too complex for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-exec` and `rm -v`:

```
find <PATH> -type f -name "<filePattern>" -mtime +1 -exec rm -v {} \;
```

`rm -v` will report what it is deleting.

Answer (score 0):

With something like this you can execute multiple commands in the exec statement, like log to file, rm file, and whatever more you should need

```
find <PATH> -type f -name "<filePattern>" -mtime +1 -exec sh -c "echo {} >>mylog; rm -f {}" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

From a shell script named `removelogs.sh`
run the command `sh removelogs.sh` in terminal

this is the text in removelogs.sh file.

```
cd /var/log;
date >> /var/log/removedlogs.txt;
find . -maxdepth 4 -type f -name \*log.old -delete -print >> /var/log/removedlogs.txt
```

- . - to run at this location **!!! so ensure you do not run this in root folder!!!**
- -maxdepth - to prevent it getting out of control
- -type - to ensure just files
- -name - to ensure just your filtered names
- -print - to send the result to stdout
- -delete - to delete said files
- >> - appends to files not overwrites > creates new file

works for me on CENTOS7